# Help with an automatic product recommender

Tags: python, automation, artificial-intelligence

I have started a new project that basically consists of a product recommender from the main internet stores that selects only the 4 best products within a specific category.

This process is done using python and pandas library and the selection is based on the global assessment of each product and the number of reviews.

I want to improve this process to incorporate the comments and detect which comments are fakes or not.

Starting from the list of comments of a product, do you have any suggestions or can you recommend a python library or other language to detect if they are fakes or not?

Thank you very much for your help.